# css - @font-face implemented font doesn't get loaded

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-family

I tried to implement a font using @font-face.
As the title suggests, it doesn't work and I have no Idea why.

I am using newest version Firefox.
I am certain the paths are correct.

edit:
the folder looks like the following:
- website
    main.html
    main.css
    - fonts
        - ProductSans
            ProductSansRegular.ttf
            ProductSansRegular.otf
            etc.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "ProductSans";
    src: url("fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.ttf") format("truetype"), url("fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.otf") format("opentype"), url("fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.woff2") format("woff2"), url("fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.woff") format("woff"), url("fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.eot") format("eot"), url("fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.svg") format("svg");
}

body {
    font-family: "ProductSans";
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        test
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: path still looks wrong - `../fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.ttf` might be better. etc

Comment: ^ Beat me to it, although I notice you get your CSS without a path, so I'm guessing it's in the same folder as your HTML. In this case, try `./fonts/ProductSans/etc...`

Answer (score 1):

Probably your fonts doesn't load because an issue with you links.

```
fonts/....
```

Will work only if your fonts folder are in same css directory.

In case your folder is outside your css folder and in the main folder of your project so you will have to use a *relative paths*, so all your link will be like this:

```
"../fonts/ProductSans/ProductSansRegular.ttf"
```

*and when you use your font use it with out double quotes.*

```
body {
    font-family: ProductSans;
}
```

[You can check here for more about font face rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp)